# Drupal commerce shopping cart pane empty for non-admin users

Tags: commerce

I have added the shopping cart pane to one of my pages so that it would show up on the review page. This works fine for the admin, but for anonoymous or authenticated users, the shopping cart pane shows up empty for the checkout page and the review page.

Is there a permission somewhere which I need to set? I couldn't find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to enable the permission for anon at Admin > People > Permissions

*"View any product of any type"*

You could try first

*"View any [type] product"*

but the former permission may still be required there.

Comment: View any product type worked! By my concern is the error message: View any product of any type
Warning: Give to trusted roles only; this permission has security implications.  -- what are the security issues?